# grunt-contrib-jshint doesn't complain about console.log

Tags: gruntjs, jshint

With the following setting the jsHint doesn't complain about `console.log` statements while it still reports `debugger` statements:

```
jshint: {
      files: [
        'Gruntfile.js',
        'js/**/*.js',
        'tests/*.js',
      ],
      options: {
        curly: true,
        immed: true,
        noarg: true,
        expr: true,
        quotmark: 'single',
        maxdepth: 3,
        browser: true,
        eqnull: true
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I can tell, JSHint has never warned about references to `console`. There is no code in there to specifically handle such references.

`console` is simply treated as an identifier that should be defined and accessible from whatever context it is referred to from (which is correct, since that is really all it is).

Therefore, you can get JSHint to warn about usage of `console` by getting it to warn about all undefined variables. Just set the `undef` option to `true`.

Then, if you want to allow the usage of `console`, you can add it to your `globals` directive or set the `devel` option to `true` (which implicitly adds it to your `globals` directive).

Comment: Ok, was confused by the `devel` options. For me it sounds like jsHint will always complain about `console` and I can mute it by `devel: true`

Comment: @AndreasKöberle - Yeah the docs don't seem very clear around that. I may open an issue on GitHub and see if it can be made a bit clearer.

Comment: For those of you reading this answer one year later, the `devel` documentation is now pretty explicit: http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/#environments

Answer (score 3):

I also had this problem.

I had `"undef"` set to `true` and still it didn't work.

I tried `"devel"` to no avail.

Finally - I simply use the `"globals"` variable like so:

```
"globals" : { 
         "console": true
}
```

and that did the trick.

Comment: You could just do `"console": false` to permit a read-only access to the `console` object.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue where I wanted the warning for references to `console`, and had `undef: true` and `devel: false`, but still not getting the warnings. Turned out to be that I had also `node: true`, which cancels that warning. After changing it to `node: false` it worked!

Comment: This works. Is there a way to warn only on console.log  and not console.error?

Comment: I don't think so. When set `console` as global, it will include both .log and .error